# Selenium : Click on a link inside a div

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm learning selenium and I'm trying a simple thing : click on the first result of a search on wikipedia.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")

# Input in the search bar
search = driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput")
search.send_keys("python", Keys.RETURN)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
first_result = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mw-search-result-heading"))
)

first_result.click()
```

So i'm able to select the heading of the first result. But I can't click on it.
I think it's because I'm clicking on the `<div>` containing the link, rather than the actual link. Here is a snippet of the HTML :

[image]

How can I target the actual `<a>` link, without it having any class name, id or name ?

Comment: `presence_of_element_located`  does not `return` the elemet - it just `returns`true` or `false` - that is , found or not  . `find_element_by_...`  methods are available to `return` the  elements.

Comment: reference for basics  -  https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: @Haezer Which that element `By.CLASS_NAME, "mw-search-result-heading"` you are trying to locate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `find_*` functions to get more specific with your WebElement queries:

```
first_result.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Selenium you might want to use `XPath`. This has saved me tons of times! simply right click on the desired tag, and click copy xpath.
then just click on the object using a similar syntax as in here:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//some_xpath')
elem.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, for sure it will be very helpful in the future ! It doesn't answer the original question thought, since the xpath of the link seems to be different for every search.

Answer (score 0):

To click on link `Python (langage)` induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use either `css selector` or `xpath` or `link_text`

**CSS Selector:**

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"searchInput"))).send_keys("python", Keys.RETURN)
first_result = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Python (langage)']")))
first_result.click()
```

**Xpath:**

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"searchInput"))).send_keys("python", Keys.RETURN)
first_result = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Python (langage)']")))
first_result.click()
```

**LINK_TEXT:**

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"searchInput"))).send_keys("python", Keys.RETURN)
first_result = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Python (langage)")))
first_result.click()
```